# drizzle orm with postgresql and nextjs14 typescript issue with migrations

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, drizzle

new to NextJS14 and Drizzle ORM.
I have read and watched some tutorials about drizzle orm and able to something like `drizzle-kit generate:pg` and `drizzle-kit push:pg` to create the migration file and then push it to make the changes to db.

I am still not sure if this is the best way to make the db change and was also looking into if there is migration history which I couldn't find any then I saw there's actually a `migrate.ts` for mysql to run in this doc `https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/migrations`.

so I created something similar which looks like this

```js
import postgres from 'postgres';
import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js';
import { migrate } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js/migrator';

const migrationsClient = postgres('postgresql://nextjs14:nextjs14@localhost:5432/nextjs14', {
  max: 1,
});
const db = drizzle(migrationsClient);

await migrate(db, { migrationsFolder: './drizzle' });
await migrationsClient.end();
```

then I tried running `npx tsx src/migrate.ts` which would give me an error because not able to compile the ts so I had to change `package.json` to include `"type": "module"`

Which then the migrate runs fine but then later realized when I try to start NextJS I would get an error of `ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope`

I did try to google this error but none of those configs are able to let me run both `migrate.ts` and `yarn dev` smoothly.

Wonder if I am missing anything or that `migrate.ts` isn't even suppose to run like that.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or results.